# How to use proxy with TwitterConsumer class from DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock

Tags: proxy, dotnetopenauth, application-blocks

I am currently implementing SSO with DotNetOpenAuth. However, when working locally, I need to send requests via a proxy. I am happy to do this programatically or via config setting but I am struggling to find where to add it to the TwitterConsumer class supplied in the application block.

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

So the easiest way is probably to [set the proxy in your .config file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex.aspx) or programmatically using [WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.defaultwebproxy.aspx).

Alternatively, just set the proxy properties on the `HttpWebRequest` objects like any other .NET request. For those request objects you don't see because DotNetOpenAuth creates and issues them automatically, you can implement `IDirectWebRequestHandler` and pass that into DNOA so you get to intercept each outgoing HttpWebRequest, but that is considerably harder and probably not necessary considering your other options.